# Make array of commands for a script

Tags: command-line, scripts, directory, cd-command

I have several directories that I need to update, and the steps are the same, except, obviously, that every directory has different names.

I'm new to making scripts. Can I make an array with e.g. `$array=('cd dir1', 'cd dir2');` and make a `for` loop that goes through every directory?

example (** ***I'm going to use php syntax*** **):

```
$arr=array('cd dir1','cd dir2', 'cd dir3', 'cd dir4', 'cd dir5')
for($i=0; $<=5; $i++){
    $arr[$i]
    #MAKE STUFF
    #MAKE MORE STUFF
    cd ..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest not storing the *commands* in an array but only the *parameters* (thanks to @steeldriver for the array syntax in bash):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dirs=('dir1' 'dir2' 'dir3' 'dir4' 'dir5')
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    cd "$dir"
    echo "***MAKE STUFF***"
    echo "***MAKE MORE STUFF***"
    cd -
done
```

Note: `cd -` (minus) changes back to the *previous* directory (instead of the parent directory) so it's safer than `cd ..`.

If you really want to store the *commands*, then you need to execute the array elements as commands by simply writing them down:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cmds=('cd dir1' 'cd dir2' 'cd dir3' 'cd dir4' 'cd dir5')
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    $cmd
    echo "***MAKE STUFF***"
    echo "***MAKE MORE STUFF***"
    cd -
done
```

Note that now there's an asymmetry in the script: The last `cd -` assumes that the `$cmd` is actually a `cd` command. I wouldn't recommend that. Either put both commands in an array or none of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do it like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# declare an array called array and define values
array=('dir1' 'dir2' 'dir3' 'dir4' 'dir5')
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    cd "$i" || exit
    #MAKE STUFF
    #MAKE MORE STUFF
    cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has already been asked (and answered) about arrays in Bash: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash).

In order to create a array of strings in Bash, you need to the **declare** keyword using -a parameter (-a for array):

```
# Array: list of strings (directories)
declare -a directories=("/bin" "/etc" "/usr")

# For each element in the array
for element in "${directories[@]}"
do
        cd $element
        ## DO STUFF
done
```

Comment: There's no need to declare. You do need to `declare -A` associative arrays, but not normal, index based ones. `array=('foo' 'bar' 'baz')` is enough.